# Spring Integration - service actor throwing error for file write operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm currently writing a sample test program to get the file and simply move to another directory (I will be adding code to process the file contents).
I'm using: Spring Boot (2.1.9.RELEASE) and Spring Integration (5.1.8.RELEASE)

I have code in place which is giving an error. (Look at the bottom of the post for the error details)

Gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration'
implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file'
```

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class IntegrationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CpKiboIntegrationApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
        return new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("outDir"));
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public MessageSource<File> pollableFileSource() {
        FileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        fileReadingMessageSource.setDirectory(new File("inputDir"));
        fileReadingMessageSource.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));

        return fileReadingMessageSource;
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class ActivatorService {
    @Autowired
    private FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler fileReceiver(Message<?> message) {
        fileWritingMessageHandler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
        fileWritingMessageHandler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
        fileWritingMessageHandler.setExpectReply(false);
        fileWritingMessageHandler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);

        return fileWritingMessageHandler;
    }
}
```

There is no error in startup, but as soon as I put the file in "inputDir" folder I get the below warnign and then error: (Note: it does perform the intended operation, file gets deleted from source and new file get created in outDir folder.)

o.s.i.expression.ExpressionUtils         : Creating EvaluationContext with no beanFactory

**Error:**

at org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(ExpressionUtils.java:86) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.getEvaluationContext(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.getEvaluationContext(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:172) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:160) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultFileNameGenerator.generateFileName(DefaultFileNameGenerator.java:70) ~[spring-integration-file-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:494) ~[spring-integration-file-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:176) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ignitiv.cpkibointegration.ActivatorService.fileReceiver(ActivatorService.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]

**Cause:**

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:284)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:265)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:223)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169)
    ... 26 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileWritingMessageHandler` must be a `@Bean`.

You are calling `new` yourself so it's not managed by Spring.

In any case, you don't want a new handler for each message.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
public MessageHandler fileReceiver() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("outDir"));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
    handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    handler.setExpectReply(false);

    handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    return handler;
}
```

Comment: I just created a bean of FileWritingMessageHandler and autowired in service class but there is no change in error message

Comment: Updated the question with modification as you suggested

Comment: FYI: After removing handler.handleMessage(message); / fileWritingMessageHandler.handleMessage(message); File not getting copied in destination directory and not even getting deleted anymore from the source folder

Comment: `return fileWritingMessageHandler;` Why?

The method should return `void`.

Why don't you just do what I suggested?

Comment: Just added void as return type and yes its working now

Comment: `return fileWritingMessageHandler;` Why? That would send the message handler as the payload of a message.


Why don't you just do what I suggested?  `@Bean @ServiceActivator(...)`.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans) a `MessageHandler` `@Bean` should be annotated `@ServiceActivator` directly. `@ServiceActivator` on a POJO method gets a message.

Comment: Thnx Gary for clarifying and pointing the error in my sample code.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to reflect return statement change. People usually view the answer and then probably comments.

Comment: My answer is correct; the proper configuration is `@Bean` that returns a `MessageHandler` and annotated as `@ServiceActivator`.